# get the base url in joomla (kunena)

Tags: facebook, url, joomla, radix

im trying to get a variable that will trow me the base url of the topic even if we are navigating on 2 3... page of the same topic in kunena forum.

This is because im implementing the facebook comments along the topics so people can be able to comment the topic also in Facebook. The problem is that facebook automaticly detect the current url, if people navigate to the second page of the topic, facebook will think that its another page, and dont make sense to have multiple paralel comments on facebook for the same topic.

Facebook also let me set the url for the page, if i can set a variable to push the base url like joomla have by default:

```
<base href="http://******.***/forum/index/generalidades/1778-amor-procura-se.html" />
```

would be awesome.
I was playing with this joomla feature to try to get the base url to joomla but this meta tags along with others , are being called by this:  wich is very hard for me to find the variable needed and put it in the follow file wich is where it is the facebook comment app:

> /public_html/components/com_kunena/template/default/view/view.php

Sorry for big post but im Portuguese and its hard for me to express myself in a few words.

Sincerely

Answer (score 0):

Use JURI:

```
$currentUrl = JURI::current();
```